# How to create 'ghost' image of table row on drag

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, clone

I created a basic jQuery script to allow dragging and dropping table rows to reorder them.  Everything is working great - the only thing that I can't figure out is how to create a 'ghost' image of the row while it is being dragged.

I tried cloning the row

```
$(this).clone().addClass('dragClone');
```

With the following CSS

```
.dragClone{opacity:0.4;position:absolute;z-index:1500;}
```

But nothing showed up.  Figuring that the TR may need to exist within a table, I cloned the entire table, emptied the rows and appended the selected TR as follows:

```
$('.dragTable').clone().addClass('dragClone');$('.dragClone').find('tbody').empty().append($('.origZone'));
```

(origZone is the class that's given to the TR being dragged)

Still nothing is showing up.

I've never used clone before, so I have no idea if I am even close, or on the right track at all! The goal is to create a ghost image similar to the one used in the Redips_drag plugin (http://www.redips.net/javascript/drag-and-drop-table-row/)

Comment: You know about JQueryUI (http://jqueryui.com/) right? It does exactly this (when using the draggable feature) and also allows sorting elements. Might be easier than trying to re-invent the wheel IMO unless you are doing this for learning? :)

Comment: Doing this for both learning, as well as for memory savings.  My draggable script is only 2kb instead of loading the full JQueryUI library!

Comment: Fair enough but you can use their site to generate a custom ui js file which only contains whatever components you actually want :)

Comment: Unless you are google.com or running something where efficiency is the ultimate paramount. A reason to *not* use jQueryUI should not be size as you can selectively choose which libraries to load. Loading it via Google's CDN means that your user likely has it cached from another website and gzipped it is only 60k. Load the draggable library only and the library will drop to the teens, easily.

Comment: I appreciate the info @Nucleon. However, I already have the rest of the my dragging script working - I would just like to figure out how to make the cloning work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by doing the following:

Creating an empty div on the page:

```
if($('#dragContain').length<1){$('body').append('<div id="dragContain"style="width:96%;height:1px"></div>');}
```

Saved the containing table to a variable, cloned it, removed the tbody contents and hid the thead, appended the row, which was saved as a variable, appended it to the previously mentioned div

```
$table=$(this).closest('.dragTable');$row=$(this).closest('tr').clone();

$table.find('tbody').remove();$table.find('thead').hide();$table.append($row);$('#dragContain').addClass('dragClone').append($table);
```

I'm not sure if this was the best way to accomplish it, but it works.

FYI - I had to use the following CSS to allow the hover affect to work on the underlying rows

```
#dragContain{pointer-events:none;}
```

Hope that this helps someone!